# Principal components of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics, numerical-methods

Recall that the Vandermonde matrix of a collection $\{x_0,\ldots,x_m\}$ of points is
$$ V = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & x_m & x_m^2 & \cdots & x_m^n \end{pmatrix} $$
Take your points to be uniformly spread out over the interval $[-1, 1]$, with step sizes $2/m$. Now use SVD to extract the first $r$ principal components of $V$.

Numerical analysis suggests that the principal components stabilize as $m$ and $n$ tend to $\infty$. Below I plot the case $r = 5$, $m = 20\,000$, $n = 1000$ to illustrate.

[image: Five principal components of V]

Is there a name for these functions?

Comment: what are you plotting exactly? One of the orthonormal basis ?

Comment: @LPZ I use SVD to approximate the Vandermonde matrix by a rank-$5$ matrix, and then I proceed to plot the first $5$ columns (i.e. a basis spanning this rank-$5$ matrix).

Comment: Your vectors appear to be a bit off. Notice that the blue, green, and yellow curves are all $\geq 0$, so they cannot be orthogonal w.r.t. the $L^2$ inner product you are trying to approximate. It looks like there is some massive jump at $x=1$?

Comment: @whpowell96 Good point, I guess you're right that somehow the inner products get killed by asymptotes at $\pm 1$.

Comment: It looks to be a numerical issue if I had to guess. This could maybe be remedied by replacing the standard inner product with one based on some quadrature that can handle the singularities but that would not relate as cleanly to the actual Vandermonde matrix and the convergence of its singular vectors

Comment: Also, can you confirm whether you are centering these vectors at all via shifting them to have mean zero? Or are you just taking the SVD of the Vandermonde matrix?

Comment: No shift @whpowell96

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively as $m,n\to\infty$, you just replace the sum over $m$ by and integral over $(-1,1)$ and the sum over $n$ as a sum over $\mathbb N$. Thus, you are interested in the right-singular eigenvectors $v$:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 x^kv(x)dx=\sigma u_k\\
\sum_{k=0}^\infty u_kx^k=\sigma v(x)
$$
In particular, they are eigenvalues of $V^TV$ or more explicitly, using:
$$
\begin{align}
(V^TV)_{xy}&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (xy)^k \\
&=\frac{1}{1-xy}\\
\int_{-1}^1\frac{v(y)dy}{1-xy}&= \sigma^2 v(x)
\end{align}
$$
You therefore just need to diagonalize the positive definite kernel.

I’m not sure sure whether these eigenvectors have simple analytical expressions despite the simplicity of the kernel. The first idea that comes to mind would be the Legendre polynomials but I couldn’t explicit a link. I’ll offer two closely related problems.

A first approach would be to modify the interval to be $(0,1)$. Indeed, you’d get:
$$
\begin{align}
(VV^T)_{kl}&= \int_0^1 x^{k+l}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{1+k+l}
\end{align}
$$
which is Hilbert’s matrix whose spectral properties are pretty standard. The eigenvectors are related to the Laguerre polynomials.

Alternatively, it would be easier if you modified the Vandermonde matrix to be:
$$
(\hat V)_{ij}=\sqrt {1+i}(x_j)^i
$$
so that the corresponding kernel would be a Bergman kernel which is also pretty standard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems that the analysis of such kernels is active research. See Zwicknagl, B. Power Series Kernels. Constr Approx 29, 61–84 (2009). https://doi.org/10.1007/s00365-008-9012-4. Analytic expressions are proving to be difficult for me.